# SQL: Join two columns of same table on two fields of another same table

Tags: sql, db2

There is the following contruct:

Table Alpha:

```
AlphaId
Name
BetaID
<some other fields>
```

An Alpha has an relation to itself and optional relations to another Alpha, 
so there is this Alpha-Alpha table, which documents this relation:

```
BetaID
AlphaId
```

For example:

Table Alpha:

```
AlphaId, Name, BetaID
100, abc, 123
101, xyz, 124
102, opq, 125
```

and table Alpha-Alpha:

```
BetaID, AlphaId 
123, 100
123, 101
124, 101
125, 102
```

with a simple join from Alpha-Alpha to Alpha I can manage

```
123, abc, 100
123, abc, 101
124, xyz, 101
125, opq, 102
```

or

```
123, 100, abc
123, 101, xyz
124, 101, xyz
125, 102, opq
```

but not both with names together.

What I want to get is this:

```
123, abc, 100, abc
123, abc, 101, xyz
124, xyz, 101, xyz
125, opq, 102, opq
```

or simply

```
abc, abc
abc, xyz
xyz, xyz
opq, opc
```

How in the world could I do this? Two joins on the same table will throw an error. If I combine the on condition with an AND or OR, I will not get the same result.

As a Bonus the possibility of kicking out self-relations would be also very cool, so that the Result may be only

```
abc, abc
abc, xyz
```

Is there any way for doing this?

Comment: In the dbms we have columns, not fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use table aliases, something like this:

```
select a1.name,a2.name
from alpha a1,alpha a2,alpha-alpha c
where a1.betaid = c.betaid and a2.alphaid = c.alphaid
```

Comment: This isn't working. I can't do a from to basically the same table. select * from alpha a1,alpha a2; is already giving an error

Comment: What SQL are you using?

Comment: Please don't use the implicit join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause).  Always explicitly list your joins.  There's a number of things that can go subtly wrong....

Comment: I use this syntax because:
1. The business logic behind the clauses is more groupable -> readable
2. Never anything went wrong because of that in the almost 20 years I've been using SQL.
However I am open to solid facts about what can go wrong and how ;)